# Can't append to scala's mutable LinkedList?

Tags: scala, scala-collections, mutable

I'm looking at the [API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/LinkedList.html) and the :+ method returns a new LinkedList. The append method will only allow the appending of another linked list. The += method needs a var to work. Why would anyone ever need these if the LinkedList is mutable? What craziness is this?

If I had something like this in Java

```
final LinkedList myList = new LinkedList<String>();
mylist.add("balh");
```

How do I achieve the same thing in Scala?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If `append` can only take a `LinkedList` then why not use

```
mylist append LinkedList("something")
```

or

```
mylist append LinkedList(otherContainer: _*)
```

There is a reason for allowing only other `LinkedList`s in `append`, I think, because this guarantees the following:

```
l1 = LinkedList(1, 2, 3)
l2 = LinkedList(4)
l3 = LinkedList(5)

l1 append l2
// l1 == LinkedList(1, 2, 3, 4)
// l2 == LinkedList(4)

l2 append l3
// l1 == LinkedList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
// l2 == LinkedList(4, 5)
// l3 == LinkedList(5)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use a `Buffer` to build your values and convert it in the data structure using `mapResult`.

```
//Create a buffer which will build a linked list
val buf = new ArrayBuffer[String]  mapResult { xs => LinkedList( xs:_* ) }

//You can append elements with +=, it is overriden to allow its use on a val
buf += "Something"
buf += "else"

//At the end you get your list
val lst = buf.result

// lst ==  LinkedList(Something, else)
```

Answer (score 3):

Mutability is on the actual elements within the list and not on the structure that the list has (persistence). This is also stated in the scaladoc.

If returning a new List each time is not what you are after, and you cannot use var, you could always use the Java `LinkedList`.

```
val mylist = new java.util.LinkedList[String]
mylist add "something"
```

I'd stick with the Scala lists, if at all possible.

Comment: Note that `java.util.LinkedList` is a doubly linked List which is something different from Scala’s `LinkedList`.

Comment: Another option is to use `scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[A]` and then `.toList` when you want a `List`.

Comment: @Debilski in which aspects is diffrent? I ask, because I can't understand which implementation of List Scala provides when typing `List(1, 2, 3)`. Is singly-linked list? Or double linked list?

Comment: `List` (= `scala.collection.immutable.List`) is an immutable singly-linked list.

Answer (score 2):

First, please pay more attention to the docs:

> This class implements **single linked lists** where both the head (elem)
>   and the tail (next) are mutable.

So what it is giving you is mutable `head` and `tail`. These operations are represented through three methods:

- `append` and `insert` change `tail`, so they receive a `LinkedList` as argument
- `update` change the `head` of an element.

If you want a class that can grow, look at the classes extending [`Growable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.generic.Growable).